# Scrapy list selector

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to iterate over a list in scrapy, this is the html sample:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href='http://example.com/' />
  <title>Example website</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='images'>
   <a href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /><img src='image1_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /><img src='image2_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /><img src='image3_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /><img src='image5_thumb.jpg' /></a>
  </div>
  <ol class="jobs">      
    <li class="job ">
        <div id="logoso-listing">
            <img width="100" height="100" class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-22824">             
        </div>
        <div id="titlo">
            <strong><a href="http://link/">Text1</a></strong>
        </div>
        <div id="type-tag"><span class="jtype permanent">Permanent1</span></div>
        <div id="type-tag-prev"><span class="jtype permanent">Permanent1</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="job ">
        <div id="logoso-listing">
            <img width="100" height="100" class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-22824">             
        </div>
        <div id="titlo">
            <strong><a href="http://link/">Text2</a></strong>
        </div>
        <div id="type-tag"><span class="jtype permanent">Permanent2</span></div>
        <div id="type-tag-prev"><span class="jtype permanent">Permanent2</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="job ">
        <div id="logoso-listing">
            <img width="100" height="100" class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-22824">             
        </div>
        <div id="titlo">
            <strong><a href="http://link/">Text3</a></strong>
        </div>
        <div id="type-tag"><span class="jtype permanent">Permanent3</span></div>
        <div id="type-tag-prev"><span class="jtype permanent">Permanent3</span></div>
    </li>
</ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

And these are the commands for the scrapy crawler:

```
content = response.xpath("//ol[@class = 'jobs']")
job_list = content.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'job')]")
for job in job_list:
    job.xpath("//div[@id = 'titlo']/strong/a/text()").getall()
```

The above code returns:

```
['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
```

While my expected output would be:

```
['Text1']
['Text2']
['Text3']
```

What am i not getting? This kind of iteration in vertical while i would like to iterate overt the `response` in a horizontal manner.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use css selector for `strong` tags with child `a` tags?

```
.css("strong a").getall()
```

You should probably add the id

```
#titlo strong a
```

For xpath

```
//*[@id='titlo']/strong/a
```

Comment: I can but i want to iterate over the list so i can access each one of the links in `<strong><a href="http://link/">Text1</a></strong>`